# Import Visual Studio TFS workspaces

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, import, workspace

Is there a way to import Visual Studio TFS workspace, I have over 30 workspace and I need to import them to a TFS on new machine.
Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to clone the *structure* of your workspaces but leave the old ones alone, run

```
tf workspace /server:yourserver /new NewName /template:OldName;OldOwner
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzy14b58.aspx

If you want to *permanently migrate* your workspaces from one machine to another, run...

```
tf workspaces /server:yourserver /updatecomputername:OldComputerName
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54dkh0y3.aspx

...then move all your files from the old box to the new one.  If you're unable to use the same paths, you'll have to update the workspace definitions.

Comment: If you only have Visual Studio installed, you will also need Team Explorer which installs `tf.exe` to e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE` for the `tf` command to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503858/how-to-get-tf-exe-tfs-command-line-client#5507337

Comment: What an atrocious path again

Comment: OldOwner looks like "Lastname, Firstname" in the tfs installation I use.

Comment: Just a quick update to this.  If you open up a VS command prompt today using VS 2017 (just do a search for command and it will show up) the tf command will be recognized without having to tool around to find it.  Also a heads up the server needs to be the full http:// server address including the collection name.  This command still works perfect in the latest version.  Just had to do it again when migrating to a new laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has documentation on this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404879.aspx

Comment: To be clear, that link is about moving your server.  I believe Murtaza is changing client machines.