# Copy TFS Working folders list from one workspace to another

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs, workspace

I got new working machine and because our TFS server is located very far from jobsites I want to avoid downloading all source codes again (several GBs) so want to move my old workspace to new one. I have copied all projects via LAN and Working folders list in Workspaces is empty in VS on new machine.

So how to move all items from old workspace to new one without adding them manually and downloading all the data again?

Comment: @Robaticus: What bad in `tfs-workspaces`? :)

Comment: @abatischev - I noticed that you were the only one using that tag, so I decrufted a bit. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's super easy to migrate your workspaces from an old machine, given your exact scenario.  See this other thread on Stackoverflow:

[Import Visual Studio TFS workspaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073284/import-visual-studio-tfs-workspaces)

Answer (score 1):

Shelve everything in your workspace and unshelve it to the new computer.  When you create the shelfset, make sure that "Preserve pending changes locally" is **not** checked.

This will, effectively move the workspace from one computer to another.

** **Update based on question being updated** **

I don't think there's an easy way for you to do what you are wanting to do within a workspace.  Instead, you should be looking at the TFS Proxy.  When you implement the proxy, it sits between your workstation and the TFS repository, and helps proxy gets, check-outs, and check-ins to help speed up your interaction with TFS.

Comment: I need not move checked-out data itself (I did it already via LAN easily) but copy info about checked-out data (i have more that 10 projects), i.e. `Working folders list` under VS:File->Workspaces