# Is there a way to check-out multiple files from various folders in TFS in a single operation

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to check-out multiple files from various folders in TFS in a single operation.

i have modified multiple files under muliple direcotries but i want them to check-out in a single click and check-in also in single click.

Thanks.

Comment: I wonder why. Is that because you don't use multiple check outs? And isn't that a bad thing to do? Check out files *after* you changed them?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, using the TFS command line client (tf.exe).

If you have tf.exe available, you could do this using the checkout command. (If you don't, take a look at this question: [How to get tf.exe (TFS command line client)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503858/how-to-get-tf-exe-tfs-command-line-client))

- Checkout command for Visual Studio 2013-2015: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/checkout-or-edit-command
- Older versions:       https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yft8zkw(v=vs.80).aspx

**Example: Separate multiple files by spaces**

```
tf checkout file2.cs file2.cs
```

**Example: Use a wildcard to search**

```
tf checkout *.csproj /recursive
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the solution explorer hold down the control key as you select files and them check them out all at once.