# Need to install tf.exe client side utility (officially known as TFVC)

Tags: jenkins, tfs, tfvc

I want to execute source control commands from command line utility.
For that, I need to install TFVC(tf.exe) 2015.

By default with VS2015 it is also installed but on my server I don't want to install VS2015 instead want to use tf.exe directly.

Any help.

Search through the internet but unable to find any direct link to download this command line client utility.

I came across this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503858/how-to-get-tf-exe-tfs-command-line-client) but all the links are broken.

Question 1: can we install TFVC without Visual Studio?
Question 2: if yes, then what are the stuff that need to be install to get that utility.

Comment: `TF.EXE` is usually installed / contained in Visual Studio. You could try the "free" community edition.

Comment: I have VS2015 in my dev machine, I want this standalone client utility for my server which has jenkins installed in it.

Comment: That was my point. I don't think there is a "standalone" installation - but I might be wrong.

Comment: Hi Ashutosh Singh, any update for this issue?Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

Which you need  actually is Team Explorer.

Team Explorer is a plug-in that installs with Visual Studio or Eclipse.  You could either install [Visual Studio Team Explorer Everywhere (TEE)](http://java.visualstudio.com/Docs/tools/eclipse) or [Team Explorer for VS2017.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/04/05/team-explorer-for-tfs-2017/) which is backward compatibility

For the older version Team Explorer, you need to go through this link: [Download older versions of Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/)

Comment: Team Explorer for VS2017 installer guide me to install Visual Studio Core Editor. I am not sure if I want this or not. What's that about?

Comment: @AshutoshSingh  Team Explorer is part of the functionality of the “Core Editor” workload, which all installations of Visual Studio include. We’re working with the folks that own the overall VS install experience to improve the “Visual Studio Core Editor” thing that you noticed. This will not infect your installation. More details info please refer the discussion in the comment from *Aaron Hallberg* in this link: [Team Explorer for TFS 2017](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/04/05/team-explorer-for-tfs-2017/)

Comment: Thanks... Will try this option. And let u knw if it succeds.

Comment: Hi  Ashutosh Singh, any update on this , did the workaround helped to figure out it ?

Comment: M sorry totally forgot. Well we didn't try that option on our server due to some constraint. So not sure abt that. Just a question for you. Have you installed it in a system that dont have VS installed in it and was able to locate tf.exe after installation??

Comment: @AshutoshSingh Yes,actually tf.exe don't need all components of VS, just need team explorer installed. For this you could take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503858/how-to-get-tf-exe-tfs-command-line-client

Comment: @AshutoshSingh this is due to Microsoft is promoting the useage of VS2017. So all the link of old version is broken.  For the older version Team Explorer, you need to go through this link: [Download older versions of Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/). Besides, if your locally build is using VS, it's also suggest you to install VS in your build server. Better to make the environment on the build server the same as local, which will significantly reduce the risk of issue occurs during the build.