# Install TFS client tools to accompany MSBuild 17.x (.net 6 / Studio 2022)

Tags: tfs, msbuild, azure-pipelines

I have installed the vsBuildTools for 2022 in order to assemble a build machine.  The build tools do not come with TFS tools to actually download source code.

Where can I get the TFS parts to finish this build server?  (I did not want a full Visual Studio 2022 install if possible)

Comment: Are you having a specific issue with your self-hosted agent? The agent comes with everything it needs to retrieve source code.

Comment: @DanielMann We're using an older version of TFS Server (2017).  While we're waiting to upgrade to devOps 2022 I'm doing the builds with powershell scripts and msBuild.  On the previous build server I installed Studio, I'm thinking I need to throw in the towel and install it : (

Comment: See [How to get tf.exe (TFS command line client)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503858/how-to-get-tf-exe-tfs-command-line-client)